# Discord.py checking user input with wait_for

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to create a log setup command like: "Are message edit logs going to be on?" if yes: send the channel id. The command im trying to create is something similar to this. My code is this. I'm a noob in discord.py. Here is the code and thanks for the help.

Note: I don't get any output when the command is executed.

```
@bot.command(name="logsetup")
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.has_any_role("Head Admininstaror", "Adminstaror", "Owner")
async def log_setup(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send("Message edit logs: On/Off")
    msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
    if msg.content.lower() == "on":
        print("Working.")
        await ctx.send("Send the channel ID.")
        msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
        editedMessageChannel = msg.content
        ctx.send("Channel is set.")
```

Comment: You are missing the `await` on the finial `ctx.send`

Comment: Yes you are right but even the send the channel id is not executed and no errors.

Comment: I just ran it on my bot. It worked fine with the await added to the `ctx.send("Channel is set.")`. Oh and since it looks like it's in a cog, make sure to add `self.` before the `bot` bits. e.g. `msg = await self.bot.wait_for(' etc...`

Comment: You can pass the command name and alias like `commands.command(name='fun', aliases=['a', 'b'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem with the help of @Kelo. Thanks to him/her, I found out that i forgot to add self.